# How to configure linux kernel so that it does not require initrd?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compiling, initramfs

What should be done in the menuconfig to compile a kernel which does not require initial ramdisk?

Comment: Before we go any further: Why is this a thing you want to do? Especially with recent kernels, the only practical use case for a non-initrd kernel would be an embedded system where every single byte of disk space and RAM has to be accounted for like  a miser counting coin. What are you trying to accomplish, and why do you believe compiling a kernel without initrd will doso?

Comment: I'm not trying to compile the kernel not to use an initrd, I noticed that linux from scratch latest systemd version does not contain initrd. I got curious about what option in the config menu does that.